# connecting to GRPC server running inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, networking, grpc

I wanted to try running a GRPC server from inside a docker container on my host. I wanted to see if i can get better performance by running it in "host" network mode. I started it from java

```
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("darthshana/lostvictoryserver:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    .withVolumes(volume1)
    .withBinds(new Bind("/home/darthshana/gameEngine/lostVictoriesServer.properties", volume1))
    .withExposedPorts(tcp5055)
    .withPortBindings(portBindings)
    .withNetworkMode("host")
    .withEnv("GAME_NAME="+gameName, "GAME_PORT=5055")
    .exec();
```

which results in the following docker container starting

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b982b240ada2        darthshana/lostvictoryserver:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   "/usr/bin/java -ja..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       angry_curie
```

on the host machine i can see it has exposed the correct port

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
tcp6       0      0 :::5055                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

and i have a firewall rule on the host

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5055 state NEW
```

which allows me to connect to the GRPC server from outside.. And everything works great!
However....
For some reason i can not connect to the grpc server from inside the same host machine.. Which im trying to do do from another java process running on the host itself (not a docker container).. I have tried

```
        ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("......", game.getPort())
            .usePlaintext(true)
            .build();
```

in the "...... " string localhost, 127.0.0.1 and also the external ip of the server which i successfully used from outside the host.. But they all don't work, GRPC call is made but it never reaches the grpc server and does not return.. I don't get any error. However if i kill the docker container i do get the error

```
2017-10-12 19:03:29.484 ERROR 3366 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Connection closed with unknown cause] with root cause

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Connection closed with unknown cause
at 

io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException
(ClientCalls.java:210) ~[grpc-stub-1.6.1.jar!/:1.6.1]
```

Its like the connection was successfull but the call didn't go through.
i have tried the same exact call from outside the host to the same grpc server running inside docker and it works fine.

Why can't i connect to it from the local host? any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you need to run the containers with `--net` property to be on the same network. But I'm struggling with this right now myself :D